# over or on - "do a little math over/on what I have left"

Tags: grammar

Here the speaker uses "over" - "do a little math **over** what I have left over". I wonder whether "on" works here as well - "do a little math **on** what I have left over."

Context:

Bill Gates on a wealth tax:

"I've paid over $10 billion in taxes. I've paid more than anyone in taxes. If I had to pay $20 billion, it's fine."

"But when you say I should pay $100 billion, then I'm starting to **do a little math over what I have left over**."
5:12 AM · Nov 7, 2019

Comment: The second example would actually probably work better than the first because 'do a little math over what I have left over' is a, repetitive, and b, slightly clunky, or non-rhythmic. Whereas the second choice: 'do a little math on what I have left over' both flows better and is more accurate because you are figuring out the problem, or doing math on what you have and not over what you have.

Comment: Thank you. I guess that in a dialogue it prefers a quick response to polished words.